# Windows service creates a .sys file frequently

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

I have created a windows service using **.Net framework 4.7** with C# as the language. This service basically fetches computer hardware information (CPU usage) and writes it to a log file (using log4net). After compiling the service in **release** mode, when i installed it using **installutil**, the service is created and upon starting the service, a file with same name as 'exe' file with extension of 'sys' gets created frequently and deleted as well. Now when i stop the service, it is no longer created. I have created few windows services in the past using .Net but never encountered such behavior.

#### Program.cs

```
static void Main()
        {
#if DEBUG
                Service serv = new Service();
                serv.StartIt();
                Thread.Sleep(20000);
                serv.StopIt();
#else
                ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
                ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[]
                {
                    new Service()
                };
                ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
#endif
        }
```

#### Service.cs

```
Timer timer = null;
        public Service()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            timer = new Timer(1000);
            timer.Elapsed += Timer_Elapsed;
        }

        private void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            SystemInfo si = new SystemInfo();
            si.GetSystemInfo();
        }

#if DEBUG
        public void StartIt()
        {
            timer.Start();
        }

        public void StopIt()
        {
            timer.Stop();
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        { }

        protected override void OnStop() { }
#else
        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            timer.Start();
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            timer.Stop();
        }
#endif
```

> Note: I am using **OpenHardwareMonitor** library to collect hardware information.

[Link to the problem description](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8ea3xlgc6732ibu/2018-05-23%2014-37-14.flv?dl=0)

Comment: Are you rebuilding performance monitor?

Comment: No @Damien_The_Unbeliever. I am trying to fetch some basic hardware information on my own.

Comment: `Link to the problem description`  (if it contains more information at all), will cancel out those of us behind corp. FWs that would like to help, because we cannot see stuff. Consider putting every relevant information directly into your question.

Comment: @Christian.K, the link contains video capture showing how the intermediate file named 'SystemInfoAgent.sys' gets created and deleted every second as long as the service is running. The windows service executable is named 'SystemInfoAgent.exe'. Rest all information is already included here. Let me know if you need additional information to diagnose this problem.